# Save log information in mysql stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, logfile

I am writing a stored procedure in mySQL and need to save log information in a text file.

Has anyone come across this?

Comment: if you mean select into outfile sure http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after long hours of searching I conclude that there are internal constraints in mySQL for direct writing text files.

The contour that occurs to me is to write the log messages and debugging on a table in the database, and then save the relevant records in a text file.

Similarly, grateful to all who may have tried to help.